# What is an out of court disposal?

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law, england-and-wales, legal-terms

Several [recent questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Out+of+court+disposal%22) have elicited answers mentioning out of court disposals. What are these?

Comment: What research effort have you made so far?  What did you learn, and what questions still remain?

Comment: Tried varus search phrases with the term on ddg but none of the results gase a type of

Comment: Gave a type of explanation that I was looking for.

Comment: Partial explanation: https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/cautioning-and-diversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are a proportionate process for concluding an investigation in to low-level offending without the need for a trail. Or  as [Avon and Somerset Police](https://www.avonandsomerset.police.uk/victims-witnesses-and-offenders/out-of-court-disposals/) put it:

> Out of court disposals are a way of dealing with less serious offending.

[South Yorkshire Police](https://www.southyorks.police.uk/find-out/out-of-court-disposals/) offers this:

> Out of Court Disposals (“OOCD’s”) are one of several methods of concluding criminal investigations without proceeding to a formal court prosecution.  They are administered to offenders to enable the police to deal proportionately with mainly (but not exclusively) low-level, often first-time offending and with a view to maximising victim satisfaction whilst addressing the offending behaviour and criminogenic needs of the offender.
>
> South Yorkshire Police currently operates a 5 tier framework for Adult OOCD's for those offenders aged 18 years and over.  This includes;
>
> - Adult ‘Simple’ Caution,
> - Adult Conditional Caution,
> - Community Resolution,
> - Penalty Notice for Disorder and
> - Cannabis/Khat Warning.

As well as repeating the above, the Sentencing Council's [Introduction to out of court disposals](https://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/explanatory-material/magistrates-court/item/out-of-court-disposals/1-introduction-to-out-of-court-disposals/) includes:

> Local authorities and other land managers can also issue fixed penalty notices as an alternative to prosecution for certain environmental and other anti-social behaviour offences.